# Return true if expression B follows A

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find an solution to return a true value if certain expression B which follows expression A is valid.

For instance -

If I'm trying to match the strings with the regex - `F[A-Z]{0,2}`

```
F
FA
FB
FAA
FAAA
```

where `F` is expression A here and `[A-Z]{0,2}` is expression B here

It is matching `FAAA` which it shouldn't since I have mentioned an quantifier max limit to 2.

So the expected output is -

```
F
FA
FB
FAA
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://regex101.com/r/1ADic0/1)

Comment: `/F[A-Z]{0,2}/` *does* match "FAAA" because you don't anchor the expression

Comment: I will be matching against a single string at a time, hence no need of anchors I thin

Comment: Or `RegExp.prototype.test` rather than `RegExp.prototype.exec` or `String.prototype.match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$` in the end to asserts position at the end of a line and also need to put `^` to asserts position at the start of a line, so that values like `BFA`, `BF` could also be ignored. So the update regex would be like:

```
^F[A-Z]{0,2}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/JyC7Wg/2)

Answer (score 2):

You need to either use:

```
\bF[A-Z]{0,2}\b
```

or

```
^F[A-Z]{0,2}$
```

you get true currently because a match does occur. You need some sort of limitation on the matching.

`F[A-Z]{0,2}` says match an `F` then 0 to 2 uppercase alpha characters. Anything before or after that can still exist.

See https://regex101.com/r/KLKTS4/2/ for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `$` to the end of your regex should fix it:

```
F[A-Z]{0,2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/1ADic0/2

The `$` sign will make sure that you are at the end of line. You can see a lot of regexps starting with `^` and ending with `$` (or `\A` and `\z` for multiline). This pattern basically means: my regexp should match the whole string.